# Error al conectar mi base de datos mongodb a traves de mongoose con javascript

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AL momento de arrancar el servidor con node app.js el servidor arranca bien, pero al momento de conectarme en el puerto a travez de mi navegador no me muestra si se conecto o no a mi base de datos, no me muestra ningun error, pero tampoco ninguna configuracion, solamente se queda "Servidor a la espera de conexion"

Al parecer mi error se encuentra en la linea donde utilizo el
app.use(express.static("public"))

Al momento de eliminar o comentar la linea, mi base de datos es conectada correctamente, pero mis archivos tienen interferencias, ya que no melos detecta, me gustaria su ayudar, muchas gracias

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")


const pass = ""
const uri = `mongodb+srv://ebratld:${pass}@cluster0.umdc50x.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

app.use(express.static("./public"))
// app.use(crud)

const connectToDatabase = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(uri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log("Base de datos conectada");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error de la base de datos: " + error);
    }
};


app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await connectToDatabase()
        console.log("Aqui estoy")
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error de la base de datos" + error)
        res.status(500).send("Error interno del servidor")
    }
    
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Servidor a la espera de conexiones")
})
```

Comment: El código como texto por favor.

Comment: Listo, he añadido el codigo, muchas gracias de antemano @René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empecemos por separar esto para que no este tan confuso:

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const { conexionDB } = require("./dbconfig");

const app = express();

conexionDB();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, resp) => {
  resp.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor en puerto 3000`);
});
```

**dbconfig.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const pass = ""
const stringDB = `mongodb+srv://ebratld:${pass}@cluster0.umdc50x.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

const conexionDB = async () => {
  try {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
    await mongoose.connect(stringDB);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Error a la hora de iniciar la BD ver logs");
  }
};

module.exports = {
  conexionDB,
};
```

Esto debería de funcionar, la verdad es que no entiendo porque abres la conexión a la base de datos en la petición. Por otro lado tener tanto el string de conexión como la contraseña en el código es un riesgo de seguridad, tienes que usar variables de entorno (.env) para almacenarlos de forma segura al igual que el puerto (al momento de desplegarlo hace que sea fácil su reasignación si el puerto que usas al momento de desarrollar esta ocupado). Te dejo la librería que más se utiliza para estos casos [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias la verdad, si me funciono esa forma, y pues en cuanto a la contraseña y demas, aun sigo estudiano y aprendiendo apenas express y mongoose, entonces de momento estoy probando como realizar las conexiones y las consultas

Pero muchas gracias, ahi leere ese enlace que me has enviado y seguire estudiando, muchisimas gracias @René